# How to avoid double spaces with csv writer

Tags: python, csv

I try to automatize Django app files (models.py, views.py, forms.py, template) production:

```
with open('views.py', 'a+', newline='', encoding="UTF8") as f1:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f1,delimiter=' ',quotechar='',escapechar=' ',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

    thewriter.writerow(['from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect',])
    thewriter.writerow(['@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")',])
    thewriter.writerow(['class PatientCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView): ',])
...
```

But my issue is that it 'converts' simple space with double space because of `escapechar = ' '`.
I can not remove this parameters as I need `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`, otherwise all my lines are delimited by double quotes.

**Expected output**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
class PatientCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
```

**Current output** *(note double spaces)*:

```
from django.shortcuts  import render,  get_object_or_404,  redirect
@method_decorator(login_required,  name="dispatch")
class  PatientCreate(SuccessMessageMixin,  CreateView):
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use the `csv` library for something that isn't a CSV file?

Comment: at first, it was csv files format ; if I simply use ```with open('mon_test.py', 'w+') as f:
    f.write('from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect\n')``` I will have to add enline seperator on each of my line and I have hundreds of lines

Comment: If you have a list of lines, you can do `for line in lines: f.write(line + '\n')`

Comment: CSV is absolutely the wrong tool, but you do realize that Python doesn't care one bit about those extra spaces, right?

Comment: And if you use the proper `print( 'from djamgo...', file=f)`, it will happily add the newlines for you.

Comment: If you absolutely want to use CSV (which is wrong), but hey, it's your thing... there is a way, given that your "rows" are all single-column, see my answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off what @Barmar pointed out, how about just writing lines:

```py
lines = [
    'from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect',
    '@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")',
    'class PatientCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView): ',
]

lines = [line + '\n' for line in lines]  # add your own line endings

# UTF-8 is default
with open('views.py', 'a+', newline='') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

---

And because I trawl SO for "CSV" and "Python", here's the CSV-Python solution...

Because your "rows" are single-column, you'll never actually need the "column delimiter" (which is what CSV is all about, breaking up columns and rows of data)...

So set it to something that isn't already a part of the data.  I chose a newline because it looks nice.  I added an extra column to the first row, `print("foo")`, to show what happens if you actually have multiple "columns of code"(?!).

***BUT***, this is certainly wrong, and I imagine some character creeping into the data/code that breaks this... because you don't want to be *encoding* lines of Python, you just want to *write* them.

Enjoy:

```py
import csv

rows = [
    ['from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect', 'print("foo")'],
    ['@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")'],
    ['class PatientCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView): '],
]

with open('views.py', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,
                        delimiter='\n',
                        quotechar='',
                        escapechar='',
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE
                        )

    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Gets me:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
print("foo")
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
class PatientCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
```